# Add values to Dataframe preserving index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a `DataFrame` (test3) which looks like this (`date` is `pd.datetime` format)

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'date': ['1890-07-01 00:00:00', '1890-07-08 00:00:00', '1890-07-15 00:00:00', '1890-07-22 00:00:00', '1890-07-29 00:00:00'],
        'date.1': ['1890-07-07', '1890-07-14', '1890-07-21', '1890-07-28', '1890-08-04'],
        'mean_temp(℃)': [23.3, 23.9, 28.3, 26.1, 26.8],
        'max_temp(℃)': [32.3, 33.2, 35.8, 33.3, 34.6],
        'min_temp(℃)': [18.9, 17.0, 22.5, 22.0, 22.3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

                          date.1  mean_temp(℃)  max_temp(℃)  min_temp(℃)
date                                                      
1890-07-01 00:00:00    1890-07-07         23.3         32.3          18.9
1890-07-08 00:00:00    1890-07-14         23.9         33.2          17.0
1890-07-15 00:00:00    1890-07-21         28.3         35.8          22.5
1890-07-22 00:00:00    1890-07-28         26.1         33.3          22.0
1890-07-29 00:00:00    1890-08-04         26.8         34.6          22.3
```

where the first column `date` is an index of dataframe.
I'm rendering new data (`rendered_date` var for `pd.to_datetime` for the first column) and (`next_value_` var `array([[28.330473]], dtype=float32)` for third column) Another columns are not important.

```py
rendered_date = render_date(last_day.index.date) # rendering new datetime object
rendered_date = pd.to_datetime(rendered_date, format='%Y/%m/%d') # making it for pandas
d = {'date':[rendered_date], 'mean_temp(℃)':[next_value_]}
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) # making new dataframe
new_df = new_df.set_index("date") # setting the same index

fr = [test3, new_df] # concating new DF with existing df (test3)
result = pd.concat(fr)
```

makes bottom of result looks like

```
....some values ....
2020-07-31 00:00:00          2020-08-06     28.7            35.0    23.9
[2020-08-07 00:00:00]        NaT            [[28.330473]]   NaN     NaN
```

which is not what I was looking for..
I just want to append data at the end of `result` dataframe(or `test3` both acceptable), preserving shape and indexes. How could I make it the same format?

Like this

```
....some values ....
2020-07-31 00:00:00          2020-08-06     28.7            35.0    23.9
2020-08-07 00:00:00          NaT            28.330473       NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Regardless of the headers, it's really not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I changed headers to english and added what I want to get at the end of article

Comment: what does `render_date` do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit***

Your code works fine for me:

```
data = {'date': ['1890-07-01 00:00:00', '1890-07-08 00:00:00', '1890-07-15 00:00:00', '1890-07-22 00:00:00', '1890-07-29 00:00:00'],
    'date.1': ['1890-07-07', '1890-07-14', '1890-07-21', '1890-07-28', '1890-08-04'],
    'mean_temp': [23.3, 23.9, 28.3, 26.1, 26.8],
    'max_temp': [32.3, 33.2, 35.8, 33.3, 34.6],
    'min_temp': [18.9, 17.0, 22.5, 22.0, 22.3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)

rendered_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-08-07')
next_value_ = 28.330473
d = {'date': [rendered_date], 'mean_temp': [next_value_]}
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(d).set_index('date')])
```

Output

```
                date.1  mean_temp  max_temp  min_temp
date
1890-07-01  1890-07-07  23.300000      32.3      18.9
1890-07-08  1890-07-14  23.900000      33.2      17.0
1890-07-15  1890-07-21  28.300000      35.8      22.5
1890-07-22  1890-07-28  26.100000      33.3      22.0
1890-07-29  1890-08-04  26.800000      34.6      22.3
2020-08-07         NaN  28.330473       NaN       NaN
```

A more idiomatic way to add one row is

```
df.loc[rendered_date] = {'mean_temp': next_value_}
# # or
# df.loc[rendered_date] = [np.nan, next_value_, np.nan, np.nan]
# # or even
# df.loc[rendered_date, 'mean_temp'] = next_value_
```

Same output on all options

---

However, if you can get all the new data and append it as a batch it will be faster than concatenating one row at a time. Python is faster to assign scalar values to native objects (like lists or dicts), while pandas is faster with vectorized calls by using numpy/C implementations.

Comment: when I remove the brackets, its says: "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional"